# Проблема с русским языком в VS (setlocale есть)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Консоль отображает русский язык нормально, но при вводе с клавиатуры русских букв

> ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ
>
> йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю

Записывает их так:
[image]

Использую getchar. Не могу понять в чём проблема. Насколько помню раньше такого не было.
Нашел решение проблемы в виде:

```
#include <windows.h>

…

SetConsoleCP(1251);

SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Но это из-за этого консоль теперь становится нечитабельной, а текст введённый в консоль отображается в Visual Studio нормально.
Ввод:

```
char* InputString(char* charset)
{
    int eIndex = -1;
    charset = nullptr;
    do
    {
        ++eIndex;
        charset = (char*)realloc(charset, (eIndex + 1) * sizeof(char));
        do
        {
            charset[eIndex] = getchar();
        } while (charset[eIndex] == '\n' && eIndex == 0);
    } while (charset[eIndex] != '\n' && charset[eIndex] != ' ');
    charset[eIndex] = '\0';
    return charset; 
}
```

Вывод:

```
cout << (*results[i]).name
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите код где выполняется ввод и вывод.

Comment: Еще, что показано на скриншоте и как оно настроено в части кодировок? Это явно не стандартный CMD.

Comment: @Cerbo это поле контрольных значений в visual studio. В консоли выводится то же самое, что и в Visual Studio. Код приложил.

Comment: Вызовы функций `SetConsole*` возвращают `TRUE`?

Comment: Разобрался с функциями SetConsole. Они работают только со шрифтом Lucida Console. И вроде всё работает. Вот только не работает теперь. У меня в программе была сортировка этих текстовых полей. Теперь ввожу например Фарадар Дараб Абв и они сортируются как Дараб Фарадар Абв. Кракозябры сортировались правильно. А вот cp-1251 нет.

Comment: Значит вы получаете не `cp-1251`, в ней русская кириллица идет по порядку.

Comment: @Cerbo всё работает. Из-за паники с локализацией сделал ошибку в алгоритме. Спасибо за наводки.